# Convert nested java objects to Jackson JSON

Tags: java, json, nested

Could someone provide an example or reference that provides a way to convert a nest JAVA object to JSON output using Jackson libraries preferably. I have no problem converting a flat JAVA object. However the JSON libraries show the nested object name and type rather than its sub-objects.  I'm pretty much leveraging the same code provided here http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/ . So I'm not attaching any code example.

e.g.

**This is what I get:**

```
{
  "fname": null,
  "lname": null,
  "addr": null
}
```

**This is what I need as output:**

```
{
    "name":null,
    "lname":null,
    "addr":{
        street:"mull",
        "city":null,
        "zip":0
    }
}
```

**This the sample class objects:**

```
import address;

public class id implements Serializable {
public String fname;
public String lname;
public address addr; 

} 

public class address implements Serializable {
public String street;
public String city; 
public int zip;
}
```

Comment: Respect the good OO and Java conventions: don't use public fields, and use getters to access the private fields. Classes start with an uppercase letter, too. And everything would be much clearer if the fields were named firstName, lastName and address.

Comment: Thank you for the good OO and Java conventions.  The names of the fields are purely an example.  Not real world.

Comment: If you follow these good conventions, everything should work as expected. If it doesn't, then post a complete example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a class Address.

```
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city; 
    private int zip;
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public int getZip() {
        return zip;
    }
    public void setZip(int zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Create a class Id.

```
 public class Id {
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private Address addr;
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public Address getAddr() {
        return addr;
    }
    public void setAddr(Address addr) {
        this.addr = addr;
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Address addressObj = new Address();
        addressObj.setCity("Chicago");
        addressObj.setStreet("Some Street");
        addressObj.setZip(12345);

        Id idObj = new Id();
        idObj.setAddr(addressObj);
        idObj.setFname("Test");
        idObj.setLname("Tester");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //Object to JSON in String
        try {
            String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(idObj);
            System.out.println(jsonInString);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "fname" : "Test",
  "lname" : "Tester",
  "addr" : {
    "street" : "Some Street",
    "city" : "Chicago",
    "zip" : 12345
  }
}
```

Comment: In my code I actually have classes setup as javabean with empty constructors, getters and setters.  The only thing that I see different is that you actually initialized the object with some real values.  I need to examine your solution more carefully to see what I'm missing that you have specified.  Thank you in any case for the detailed example.

Comment: I changed the class variables to how you have used. i.e. for example,  public String city in Address class. Which would mean addressObj.city = "Chicago"; in main method. Still works fine.

Comment: @bbboomer . Ok. I think I have it. What you are trying to do is this: Address addressObj = new Address(); Id idObj = new Id(); ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); and then displaying the result. What you should be doing to get the expected result as you want is this: Address addressObj = new Address(); Id idObj = new Id(); *idObj.addr = addressObj;* ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); You basically did not assign the addressObj to the variable addr in object of Id.

Comment: Hardi,  thank you for taking the time to understand the problem.  It always seems obvious when you see the answer :-)

Answer (score -2):

you have not initialized anything in class "id" and that is why everything is null. if you create an object of address and assign it before you convert object to json, you will get the structure you want. something like following.

```
public static void main( String args[] ){
id i = new id();
address a = new address();
i.serAddress( a );
//do writeValueAsString here
}
```

NOTE: Follow proper [naming for class and variables](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Comment: I'm not looking for values in the object yet.  I'm just trying to convert the java object to a JSON output.

Comment: if the object address itself is null, your json will not contain any value, your first output value shows all fields of class id are null while second output(which you want) says, class id has all fields null except address. address is initialized but none of the attribute of address has value. hope this clarifies your doubt. without assigning address you will not be able to get the json as you expect.