# calling a Webservice returns JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am working on spring based application. 
Below is the rest webservice method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = MyRequestMapping.GET_SIG_DATA, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> getSigDataValues(@PathVariable final String acc, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        List<String> dataList = null;
        try {
             //logic goes here
        } catch (Exception e) {
             LOG.error("Exception" + e);
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

The above webservice is not returning any responseDTO object, it just returns a list of String type.

I want to call above webservice from another application.Below is my code.

```
 public List<String> getSigData(String acc){

       try{
    list= (List<String>)restTemplate.postForObject(DataURL.GET_SIG_DATA.value(), MyRequestDTO.class,MyResponseDTO.class, acc);
        }
        catch (final RestClientException e)
        {
            LOG.info("RestClientException :" + e);
             String errorMsg = StringUtils.EMPTY;
            if (e instanceof HttpStatusCodeException)
            {
                errorMsg = ((HttpStatusCodeException) e).getResponseBodyAsString();
            }
            else
            {
                errorMsg = e.getMessage();
            }
            LOG.error("error message : : " + errorMsg);
          }
}
```

When i am calling the above webservice call, its giving me below exception message:

```
 RestClientException : org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
 INFO  [STDOUT] error message : {"type":"JsonMappingException","message":"General error"}
```

Please suggest, as the webservice call returns list as JSON object, do i need to handle at client side?
How can i call the above mention webservice in getSigData(..) method.

Comment: Are you using a converter to convert list of strings to JSON?

Comment: No, iam not using any converter. So if my webservice returns List<String> can other application call that as shown in the above code. Then why is it throwing me JsonMappingException?

Comment: You will need a converter for converting objects to JSON and vice versa. Jackson can be used for this. Pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841114/angularjs-form-post-data-giving-null-values-in-my-spring-controller/39842119#39842119 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851336/spring-utilizing-mongo-implementation-over-jpa/39852442#39852442. If this is what you mean. Let me know. I can give a better understanding as an answer with code on how to achieve this.

Comment: @HARDI - Thanks for the info..If the webservice returns a MyResponseDTO object then also do we need to have a converter? If webservice is returning a DTO object instead of List as in my case and if it works then i can change my webservice method to return a DTO object. Please suggest.

Comment: My understanding is that Spring does not have an inbuilt parser/converter for converting java objects to JSON and vice versa. So yes, you would need a converter. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125137/discussion-between-hardi-and-user222).