# cannot call a webservice which is retuning List value

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am working on spring based application. I have a REST webservice which is returning List. From my application when i tried to call that service it is throwing me the follwong exception.

```
RestClientException : org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
 INFO  [STDOUT] error message : {"type":"JsonMappingException","message":"General error"}
```

Please suggest how can i retrieve that webservice and read the List values.
I already posted a question on this. Please check the below link for complete details.

[calling a Webservice returns JsonMappingException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902869/calling-a-webservice-returns-jsonmappingexception?noredirect=1#comment67097276_39902869)

Comment: Show us the code where you query that service.

Comment: @rorschach - Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902869/calling-a-webservice-returns-jsonmappingexception?noredirect=1#comment67097276_39902869 . Entire code is posted ther.